# Is the destination of a commercial flight important for the pilot?

Tags: navigation, flight-planning

As has been recently advertised ([in here](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/uk-british-airways-flight-lands-in-edinburgh-scli-gbr-intl/index.html), [here](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2019/mar/25/british-airways-flight-dusseldorf-lands-edinburgh--mistake), [here also](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-47691478)), a recent British Airways flight from London City Airport destined for Düsseldorf mistakenly flew its passengers to Edinburgh instead.

I'm a layman in terms of aviation, but I (and I'm sure many more do) do see aviation as a strictly regulated area full of double-checks, double instruments (even 2 pilots!) to make sure an airplane is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing.

Perhaps mine is a rather car-centric view, but I can't imagine starting the engine of the car without knowing clearly where I'm heading, which landmarks, roads (and so on) I'm supposed to pass by during the route.

**TL;DR:**

Must (or should) both pilots know where he airplane they are flying is going to? Or do they simply follow an approved flight path?

Comment: In reality that flight was not operated by BA, rather it was a flight contracted from BA to a 3rd party. The pilots received information to go to Edinburgh and that's what they executed: this probably because of a mistake that happened in the chain of control. The only thing I am wondering is what they said on the PA

Comment: @Afe A simple call from the pilots: "Our estimated flight to Edinburgh is 1-hour and weather is fine there" should suffice!

Comment: I was on a flight once where the pilot said, "Just checking everybody on the plane either *wants* to or *has* to go to [small backwater town]."

Comment: @gmauch everyone was already sleeping before T/O?

Comment: Flying surely is nice regardless where but much less so about the landing. Somewhat strange question. Voting to close.

Comment: The suggested "duplicate" question, discussing Gross Navigation Error checks, is about a separate topic. That's about getting off of the course you intended to fly. That isn't what happened in the referenced incident; the crew landed at the airport they intended to land at -- no navigation error occurred.  The error that did occur was elsewhere in the process, & no check for navigation errors would have caught it. Close the question as "goofy" if you want, but it isn't a dupe.

Comment: If you're a limo driver and you're told to go pick up some kids and take them to prom at a local high school, you wouldn't have any reason to question whether your dispatcher might've told you the wrong high school...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The pilots in this case *did* know where they were going: Edinburgh.

[BA said a paperwork error was to blame, with the pilot following orders from Germany, where WDL’s head office had filed the incorrect flight plan.](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2019/mar/25/british-airways-flight-dusseldorf-lands-edinburgh--mistake)  The pilots flew according to the flight plan they were given, and ATC happily routed their plane along that flight plan as well.  The pilots had no reason to suspect the flight plan was incorrect, and safety was never compromised.

The dispatchers involved could use improvement, though.

Comment: Would a reference improve this answer?

Comment: added reference

Comment: So the pilots aren't always aware of what the passengers' tickets say?  Never really thought there'd be a knowledge gap there.

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't remember ever being on a flight where the crew didn't say "Welcome aboard... service to <destination>"... although whether anyone would say anything if they said the wrong destination I don't know.

Comment: @TemporalWolf - I'm just thinking in this specific case, I wonder if the pilots said "Welcome aboard your flight to Edinburgh.", and ...nobody said "Uhhh, what?" before takeoff.

Comment: @BruceWayne I’ve actually had the pilot say the wrong destination in their announcement before, they came back on the TA 5 minutes later to apologise and said the correct destination, presumably because someone pointed it out to them. Maybe on this relatively short flight no one was able to point it out straight away and it was easier to carry on to Edinburgh then get a new flight plan once back on the ground.

Comment: Various articles indicate passengers realized something was wrong when the pilot made the pre-arrival announcement. No mention of a pre- or post-departure announcement, so either one wasn't made or nobody noticed the mismatch.

Comment: Forget needing announcements. I'm genuinely surprised none of the passengers noticed they never crossed water (the English Channel), or didn't distinguish the geography (Belgium vs Scotland), or didn't use their GPS once. Until they figured it out on the pre-landing announcement.

Comment: @smci Some did notice, but too late, perhaps. Check the first link on my question: ..."she realized something wasn't right when she saw mountains outside the plane, instead of the "usual German industrial landscape."
"When we started descending and I saw some taller hills/mountains, I did think that this isn't how Eastern Netherlands/Western Germany should look like but I assumed we took some small detour," she said. "Then my colleague sitting across the aisle from me told me to check Google Maps -- and it showed us being around Carlisle."

Comment: @gmauch: I had already read it before I posted, that's exactly what I was referencing. Ok so "on descent or pre-landing", nearly same thing. I'm stunned noone noticed the absence of English Channel early on. The point is this "Duh!" moment came hours too late to be useful.

Answer (score 16):

For commercial flying, yes both pilots should know where they are going and the general direction/course they are flying but they do in-fact follow an approved path and are subject to ATC vectors. The reality is that pilots who fly short haul may fly numerous flights in a day to various destinations with limited time in between flights to regroup. Flight plans, load sheets and planning may very well be done by a dispatcher and simply handed to the crew when they arrive at the aircraft. It is possible to get confused, typically there is some navigational programing or FMS input that would force the pilot to review the path. However confusion like this has occurred before as was the case with [Varig Flight 254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varig_Flight_254) which simply entered the wrong heading into the autopilot and ended up lost and low on fuel.

In the case of general aviation this may be less of the case. While generally you take a small plane up to go from one place to another there are those that pull [the old cub out on the weekend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_J-3_Cub) and just go fly around the area to do some sightseeing. This is more just for the joy of flying...